# SItecore WFFM trackig field data?

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using sitecore 7.2 rev. 140228, We have some default tracking in Sitecore WFFM that could be seen in advance field under standard fields.
[image]
Client asked us where is report for this tracking and where we can review this events etc ... I have tried but could not found any way to get this tracking report.

Comment: This isn't a progamming question. Likely a better fit for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are WFFM reports in your Sitecore desktop under the Sitecore start button -> All Applications -> Web Forms Form Marketers -> Form Reports

In there, you can select the form you want to see the report of. Reports include things such how many people have filled in the form, how many dropped out and the values of the fields when they are filled (if you've enabled form dropout tracking).

Alternatively, if you're just interested in which goals have been triggered on which page you could potentially find this in the Executive Dashboard (haven't used 7.2 in a while so not sure anymore which data it shows) or you'd have to write a SQL query and query the database.

Comment: You are right but in WFFM report we can see dropout form but could not view these event's/ goal.
I wants to know that which events/goal are triggered against which pages/form but in executive dashboard we don't have such category to filter or review.
Thanks for support !

Comment: I'd suggest either looking at the Executive Dashboard or go to the SQL database direct as mentioned in my answer - you should be able to create a relatively simple SQL query to check the goals/ page events per item if the Executive Dashboard doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use button "Form Reports" on your ribbon:
[image]

Comment: Thanks but we do't have these events/goals in Form Reports.